# Analog Clock in JS shows the wrong hour and minutes

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a JavaScript analog clock, the hands are moving correctly but  I don't know why is showing me the wrong hour and minutes. The timezone used in Date is ok but its like the function isn't taking it.

Anyone can help me out finding the error?
Sorry for my english, I'm also new in stack overflow :(

```js
const handHour = document.querySelector("#hour");
const handMin = document.querySelector("#minutes");
const handSec = document.querySelector("#seconds");

function getSecondsSinceStartOfDay() {
  const day = new Date();
  var seconds = day.getSeconds();
  var secondsHand = ((seconds / 60) * 360) + 90;
  handSec.style.transform = `rotate(${secondsHand}deg)`;
  var minutes = day.getMinutes();
  var minutesHand = ((minutes / 60) * 360) + ((seconds / 60) * 6) + 90;
  handMin.style.transform = `rotate(${minutesHand}deg)`;
  var hours = day.getHours();
  var hourshand = ((hours / 12) * 360) + ((minutes / 60) * 30) + 90;
  handHour.style.transform = `rotate(${hourshand}deg)`;
}
setInterval(getSecondsSinceStartOfDay, 1000);
```

```css
#circle {
  background-color: #363646;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 6px solid #938aa9;
  position: relative;
}

#circle .num {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #dcd7ba;
}

#circle .num1 {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

#circle .num2 {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

#circle .num3 {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#circle .num4 {
  transform: rotate(120deg);
}

#circle .num5 {
  transform: rotate(150deg);
}

#circle .num6 {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

#circle .num7 {
  transform: rotate(210deg);
}

#circle .num8 {
  transform: rotate(240deg);
}

#circle .num9 {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

#circle .num10 {
  transform: rotate(300deg);
}

#circle .num11 {
  transform: rotate(330deg);
}

#minutes,
#hour,
#seconds {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform-origin: top center;
}

#hour {
  background-color: #e6c384;
  height: 100px;
  width: 8px;
  transform: rotate(125deg);
}

#minutes {
  background-color: #6a9589;
  height: 120px;
  width: 4px;
  transform: rotate(255deg);
}

#seconds {
  background-color: #9cabca;
  height: 127px;
  width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle">
  <div id="hour"></div>
  <div id="minutes"></div>
  <div id="seconds"></div>
  <div class="num num1">1</div>
  <div class="num num2">2</div>
  <div class="num num3">3</div>
  <div class="num num4">4</div>
  <div class="num num5">5</div>
  <div class="num num6">6</div>
  <div class="num num7">7</div>
  <div class="num num8">8</div>
  <div class="num num9">9</div>
  <div class="num num10">10</div>
  <div class="num num11">11</div>
  <div class="num num12">12</div>
</div>
```

**Here is the whole project running**: https://codepen.io/annierod/pen/rNdvzjR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your math was off slightly. Instead of adding 90 to the hours, minutes, and seconds you want to add 180.

```js
const handHour = document.querySelector("#hour");
const handMin = document.querySelector("#minutes");
const handSec = document.querySelector("#seconds");

function getSecondsSinceStartOfDay() {
  const day = new Date();
  var seconds = day.getSeconds();
  var secondsHand = ((seconds / 60) * 360) + 180;
  handSec.style.transform = `rotate(${secondsHand}deg)`;
  var minutes = day.getMinutes();
  var minutesHand = ((minutes / 60) * 360) + ((seconds / 60) * 6) + 180;
  handMin.style.transform = `rotate(${minutesHand}deg)`;
  var hours = day.getHours();
  var hourshand = ((hours / 12) * 360) + ((minutes / 60) * 30) + 180;
  handHour.style.transform = `rotate(${hourshand}deg)`;
}
setInterval(getSecondsSinceStartOfDay, 1000);
```

```css
#circle {
  background-color: #363646;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 6px solid #938aa9;
  position: relative;
}

#circle .num {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #dcd7ba;
}

#circle .num1 {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

#circle .num2 {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

#circle .num3 {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#circle .num4 {
  transform: rotate(120deg);
}

#circle .num5 {
  transform: rotate(150deg);
}

#circle .num6 {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

#circle .num7 {
  transform: rotate(210deg);
}

#circle .num8 {
  transform: rotate(240deg);
}

#circle .num9 {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

#circle .num10 {
  transform: rotate(300deg);
}

#circle .num11 {
  transform: rotate(330deg);
}

#minutes,
#hour,
#seconds {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform-origin: top center;
}

#hour {
  background-color: #e6c384;
  height: 100px;
  width: 8px;
  transform: rotate(125deg);
}

#minutes {
  background-color: #6a9589;
  height: 120px;
  width: 4px;
  transform: rotate(255deg);
}

#seconds {
  background-color: #9cabca;
  height: 127px;
  width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle">
  <div id="hour"></div>
  <div id="minutes"></div>
  <div id="seconds"></div>
  <div class="num num1">1</div>
  <div class="num num2">2</div>
  <div class="num num3">3</div>
  <div class="num num4">4</div>
  <div class="num num5">5</div>
  <div class="num num6">6</div>
  <div class="num num7">7</div>
  <div class="num num8">8</div>
  <div class="num num9">9</div>
  <div class="num num10">10</div>
  <div class="num num11">11</div>
  <div class="num num12">12</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!! I don't know why I struggled so much with converting the time and let that pass. Sorry!